# ApacheCamelでインポートしたプロジェクトのルートを使用したい

Tags: apache-camel

#### 質問

ApacheCamelのJavaDSLでAPIを作成しています。
下記の手順でインポートしたプロジェクトのルートを使用しようとするとエラーになりました。
他プロジェクトのルートを使用する方法等、何か解決方法のヒントをご教授いただけませんでしょうか。

#### 手順

1. Aプロジェクト内にAルートを作成し、Mavenプライベートリポジトリにあげる
2. BプロジェクトのpomファイルにAプロジェクトの情報を記載し、インポートする
   　※Aプロジェクト内のBeanをBプロジェクトで使用できることは確認済
3. Bプロジェクトのルート上で`.to("direct:Aルート")`というように呼び出す

#### その他設定等

・Aプロジェクトのルート部分

```
package jp.co.aaa.route;
public class ARoute extends RouteBuilder {
  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("direct:acheck")
    .routeId("acheck")
    .transform(simple("${body}"));
  }
}
```

・Bプロジェクトの呼び出し部分

```
package jp.co.bbb.route;
～～
private void bCheck(){
   from("direct:bcheck")
   .routeId("bcheck")
   .to("direct:acheck");
}
```

・Bプロジェクトのcamel-context.xmlに下記の通りpackageScanを追加

```
<packageScan>
    <package>jp.co.aaa.route</package>
    <package>jp.co.bbb.route</package>
    <includes>**.*</includes>
</packageScan>
```

#### エラー内容

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No consumers available on endpoint: Endpoint[direct://XXXAルートXXX]. Exchange[ID-HW3650-3230-1517360482872-41-8] while invoking public abstract java.lang.Object jp.co.XXXXXX(java.lang.String) with params [XXX].
```

Comment: Aルートのfromエンドポイントはどのように定義されていますか。差し支えない範囲で、Aルート全体の定義も上げてもらえるとトラブルシュートしやすくなります。ちなみに、to("direct:xxx")ではfrom("direct:xxx")と定義されたエンドポイントしか呼び出せません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。本文に、ルート呼び出しまわりのソースを追記しました。to("direct:xxx")の部分とfrom("direct:xxx")が合致していることを確認しました。

Answer (score 1):

こちら、自己解決しました。

Bプロジェクトcamel-context.xml中のpackageScanを下記の通り修正したところ、読み込みに成功しました。

```
<bean id="aRouteBuilder" class="jp.co.aaa.route.ARouteClass" />
<bean id="bRouteBuilder" class="jp.co.bbb.route.BRouteClass" /> 

<camelContext ...>
    <routeBuilder ref="aRouteBuilder"/>
    <routeBuilder ref="bRouteBuilder"/>
...
</camelContext>
```

ありがとうございました。